# RCP application throws UnsupportedClassVersionError for org.eclipse.osgi

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp

New to RCP application. While running the application as Launch an eclipse application it throws below error wrt org.eclipse.osgi

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version     52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Reduced the Env variable to 1.6 from 1.8

Eclipse version: Indigo

Below is my eclipse ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-vm
C:\DEV\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5

-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Please convey if im missing some thing

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: Kindly provide more details

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any question here to answer.

Answer (score 0):

A dependent jar was compiled on jdk 1.8. Recompiled using 1.6 and it worked